# Remove "Upsell" tab on product page

Tags: template, up-sells

On the product page, there's a tab called "Upsell". I do not need to use this feature. How do I remove this tab?

Comment: Did you manage to get the issue resolved?

Answer (score 3):

In your templates `local.xml` you can remove the block by adding the following snippet. This however only works if you use the Magento base or RWD theme

```
<catalog_product_view>
   <reference name="product.info">
      <remove name="product.info.upsell"/>
   </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. Where can I find that file? I'll see if I can find similar in my theme. This theme is located in the /rwd folder.

Comment: app/design/{PACKAGE}/{YOURTHEME}/layout/local.xml - if you do not have this, create a blank file with the following in the header and call it local.xml: `<?xml version="1.0"?> <layout version="0.1.0">  {.... everything comes in here ...} </layout>`